# Why is so much more gas used by instantiate than instantiateWithCode in the contracts pallet?

Tags: pallet-contracts

When I call instantiateWithCode, I need around 288,000,000 gas. But to call instantiate (having already uploaded the code separately) I need 75,000,000,000.

I would have expected the more simple instantiate to require less gas but the opposite is the case.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand the difference between `gas_consumed` and `gas_required`. The latter one is what you need to set as `gas_limit` and the former one is what is actually consumed and what is payed fees on. I assume that you are referring to `gas_required` here.

The reason for that value being higher for `instantiate` is that we cannot know how big a contract code is before loading it from storage. Hence we need to pre-charge the maximum contract size and then refund it after loading. This leads to a spike in gas which can push `gas_required` higher than `gas_consumed`. If that actually is the case depends on how much gas is consumed later during contract execution. `instantiate_with_code` doesn't have this issue as the code is not loaded from storage but passed as part of the extrinsic.

When comparing the value of `gas_consumed` instead of `gas_required` it should be in fact higher for `instantiate_with_code`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Great explanation. Obvious in hindsight!